# Why is the CSS for my theme not loading while the JS is?

Tags: theming, 8, .info

Theme `mytheme` is placed under `/sites/all/themes/`

Content of `mytheme.info.yml` :

```
name: My Theme
type: theme
description: Custom theme.
core: 8.x
base theme: classy
version: 8.x-1.0
libraries:
  - mytheme/global-styling
regions:
  logo: 'Logo'
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  page_header: 'Page Header'
  content: Content  # the content region is required
  page_sidebar: 'Page Sidebar'
  contact_first: 'Contact (First column)'
  contact_second: 'Contact (Second column)'
  contact_third: 'Contact (Third column)'
  footer_logo: 'Footer logo'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
  footer_second: 'Footer second'
  footer_third: 'Footer third'
  footer_copyright: 'Footer Copyright'
regions_hidden:
  - sidebar_first
```

Content of `mytheme.libraries.yml` :

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css: { minified: true }
      assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: { minified: true }
      assets/css/style.css: {}
      assets/fonts/montserrat/montserrat.css: {}
  js:
    assets/plugins/jquery-1.11.1.min.js: { minified: true }
    assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js: { minified: true }
    assets/plugins/moderniz.js: {}
    assets/js/app.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

The JS is loading but the CSS isn't. How come?

Comment: If you replace `//` with `https://`, does it work? Just trying to validate the issue is the `//` at the beginning.

Comment: I removed the line. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the google fonts entry in quotes like this:

```
'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&subset;=latin,cyrillic': { type: external }
```

Maybe there is a problem with the url using yaml special characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109912/do-i-need-quotes-for-strings-in-yaml#22235064

Comment: Unfortunately... doesn't work!